# Re-Bootstrap Elastic Cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, bootstrapping, elk

I need guidance to reinstate my `Elastic cluster`.
I had bootstrapped `Elastic Cluster` and had created 1 `super-user` and 2 other `system-users` too.
`Ingest`, `Data`, `Gateway` nodes had also joined the cluster.
Later, I felt I want to rename the `Data`  but `Google-Cloud` does not allow me to rename so I created new data nodes with proper name and then deleted the old data nodes.
I had not ingest any data so far, no index was created .
Now, when I tried to see any of the cluster details ( say license information).
It does not authenticate any system user.
I tried re-creating the `Bootstrap` password and setting again. But that did not work either.

I'm seeing below exception in `Elastic` logs.

```
failed to retrieve password hash for reserved user [username]
org.elasticsearch.action.UnavailableShardsException: at least one primary shard for the index [.security-5] is unavailable
```

Please suggest me, there is a way to reinstate the existing configurations or how can I bootstrap it again .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the sudo access, I created a system user using [file based auth](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/file-realm.html)
then re-created other system users with the same password
then reverted the access type to normal login
That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> I had not ingest any data so far

If you haven't added any actual data yet, the simplest approach is probably to delete all the current data directories and start the cluster from scratch again.

Also, is this still Elasticsearch 5 (looking at `.security-5`)? Because that's a really old version and some things work differently there than with current versions for a proper reset.